# How to use ExecutorService with multiple runnable to display data in android gridview?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have to fetch data from server in mobile database and need to display in `gridView` according to date provided to server.
I have fetch data from server in one `asynctask` and stored in database in android. But to display in grid view i Have used `runnable` to get data from database but if user tries to changes date filter. There will be again server call and data from data base will get replace and there all date `runnable` will get started. But is this if previous `runnable` is not completed then there will be conflicts which data to show.

So i am thinking about providing `runnable` to **ExecutorService**. I am not able to stop previous active runnable. need help?

Answer (score 0):

`ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` is intended to stop all executing threads.